# Describing equivalence classes of ad=bc mod n

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Let $G = \{1,2,3,4\}$, and let $H = G\times G$. Define a relation $R$ on $H$ as follows:
$$
(a,b)R(c,d) \text{ if and only if } ad \equiv bc \mod 5.
$$
 a. Show that $R$ is an equivalence relation.

b. Describe the equivalence classes of $R$.

I think I did alright with part a, but I am struggling with part b. Should I use matrix to describe all equivalence classes, or just write something like:
$[e]=\{a,b,c,d \in G \mid e = (ad - bc) \div 5, e\in Z \}$. And if I am going to use matrix, how should I do it? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not that every element $a$ in $G=\{1,2,3,4\}$ has an inverse $b^{-1}$ $\mod 5$ so that $b.b^{-1}=1 \mod 5$ if you're allowed to use this then we can define the equivalence classes using the inverse.

First an equivalence class is the set of pairs $(a,b)$ which "are related" by $R$, So the equivalences classes can only be defined by the value of $ab^{-1} \mod 5$, because for any pair $(a,b)$ if we know the value of $ab^{-1} \mod 5$ then we can deduce if another element "are related" to this $(a,b)$, so it's very useful to define the equivalence classes as:
$$\left[e\right]=\left\{(a,b)\in G^2\Big / ab^{-1}\equiv e \mod 5 \right\} $$

so that there is exatly $4$ classes : $[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]$.

Comment: Sorry I did not observe that, I think that if you allow using _inverses_ then you can reread my answer (I edited it)

Answer (score 0):

*Note: This answer builds on concepts that you may not have seen in a "discrete mathematics" course. I hope to provide some perspective in case you, or some other later reader, **have** seen them. Otherwise you may prefer one of the other answers.*

This particular equivalence relation is how one defines the [field of fractions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_of_fractions) of an arbitrary integral domain. The pair $(a,b)$ is going to represent the fraction $\frac ab$.

In this case the integral domain is the integers modulo 5. However, since this is already a *field*, it is its own field of fractions, so we should expect exactly one equivalence class for each element of $G$. Namely, $a\in G$ corresponds to the equivalence class containing $\frac a1 = (a,1)$.

Knowing how to work with fractions in the familiar $\mathbb Z$-to-$\mathbb Q$ case, we can then see that the equivalence classes must be
$$ [a] = \{(ag\bmod 5, g)\mid g\in G\} $$
for every $a \in G$.

(Actually we're missing the zero. The *actual* construction of the field of fractions would have $H=R\times (R\setminus \{0\})$ where $R=\{0,1,2,3,4\}$, so $R\setminus\{0\}$ is what the exercise calls $G$).